# UITableView CustomCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to do some operation in a particular cell using some function.

Here i used button in custom cell to call this function.
Each button has cell index value as title.
Using that title only, I can identify a particular cell to do some operation.

```
-(void)showInteractionView:(id)sender{
     UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
     lastSelInteractionVal=[btn.titleLabel.text intValue];

     NSIndexPath *index=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[btn.titleLabel.text intValue] inSection:0];
     UITableViewCell *cell=[tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];

     UIView *v=(UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:INNERVIEW];

     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

     v.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100);

     [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

But here I used custom cell so I want to assign `tblView` cell to a custom cell instead of this code below.

```
UITableViewCell *cell=[tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];
```

Please give me a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you can get custom cell.

```
YourCustomCell *customCell = [tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];
```

or you can do this

```
id Cell = [tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];
if([cell isKindOfClass[yourCustomCellClassName class]]){
  NSLog(@"Custom Cell Found");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response....I used CustomCell *cell=[tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:index]; but it shows warning as Incompatible pointer types initializing 'CustomCell *' with an expression of type 'UITableViewCell *'..so what can i doo.

Comment: You need to typecast, i.e.: `CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];`